# Circular inheritance? What?

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, recursion, super

So I've been messing around in python and I don't understand what the shell is going on with this.

I start by writing these classes in this order.. comments are my understanding of what's happening:

```
# class A1 inherits object
class A(object):
    pass

# class B1 inherits A1, object
class B(A):
    def a(self):
        print "b",
        super(B, self).a()

# class A2 inherits B1, A1, object
class A(B):
    def a(self):
        print "a",
        super(A, self).a()

# class B2 inherits A2, B1, A1, object
class B(A):
    def a(self):
        print "b",
        super(B, self).a()
```

When I create an instance of `A` *which is A2* and call `A.a`,

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.a()
a b

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#263>", line 1, in <module>
    a.a()
  File "<pyshell#258>", line 4, in a
    super(A, self).a()
  File "<pyshell#256>", line 4, in a
    super(B, self).a()
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

I thought the error would be (*as Kevin suggests*) `AttributeError: A instance has no attribute 'a'` because I expected `A2 > B1 > A1 (no a function) Crash`

Even more curious,. when I now create an instance of `B`, even more unexpected results happens..

```
>>> b = B()
>>> b.a()
b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a b a ...
```

Shouldn't this crash the same way `A` did, but just one function more?
What?

Comment: Did you just forget the `2`s in the sample code here?

Comment: @his I want to overwrite the name though. The numbered class comments are just for referencing

Comment: @Calpratt what on earth are you trying to do?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm just playing around with the shell and I came across this. I just want to understand why it doesn't crash

Comment: _"I get an error as expected when the call travels"_. But are you getting the error you expect to get? Personally, I'd expect to see `AttributeError: A instance has no attribute 'a'`, not `super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`. It looks like it's failing in B1, not in A1.

Comment: @Kevin hmmmmm I shall change it.

Comment: @Kevin calling `a2.a()` and `b1.a()` I get `AttributeError` before `B` is redefined, `TypeError` after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating class `A2` and class `B2`, the lines

```
super(B, self).a()
super(A, self).a()
```

Use the type `A2` and `B2` respectively for all class functions, `A2.a`,`B1.a`,`B2.a`..

This means that when I call `A2.a`, the super calls the base class `B1.a`. In `B1.a` the function attempts to use the `super` function with type `B2` and a instance of `A2`.. thus giving a `obj must be an instance or subtype of type` error.

When I call `B2.a`, the super calls `A2.a` then calls `B1.a` where upon calling `super` with type `B2` and an instance of `B2` once again calls the `A2.a` function... Where it will loop indefinitely until a recursion error is thrown!

So it ends up only looking like a circular inheritance, when really its just two circular functions given a particular parameter.